# Grails. Ways to set the timeout interval of a session. Which better?

Tags: grails, session-timeout

I know two ways to set the timeout interval of a session:

way 1:

```
grails install-templates
```

Then edit `src/templates/war/web.xml`

way 2:

write this line of code in your controller:

```
session.setMaxInactiveInterval(sec);
```

Which of these ways do you think is better - and why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Changing the value in web.xml is best if you want a constant value for all sessions.

`setMaxInactiveInterval` is useful when you want to programmatically determine the current session's max length, but it's overkill to just set the value repeatedly to the same value.

Comment: When setting `session-timeout` in web.xml, does it have a max allowed value?

Comment: I don't think so. You can set it to -1 to never expire, but this is probably a bad idea unless you have some sort of process to find and invalidate unused sessions.